# Commonly getting DNS failure calling tf.io.gfile methods from GKE: "Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster set up in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), with preemptible instances, TPU support, and 1 container per node.

About twice per container per day I get this error calling e.g. `tf.io.gfile.glob(...)`:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6 meaning 'Couldn't resolve host name', error details: Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com' when reading gs://bucket/dir/dir

It only happens in GKE, not when running directly on a compute VM in Google Cloud.

Is this something I should just expect in GKE and handle (e.g. back off and retry), or is there some kind of networking config issue or other underlying problem that I can do something about?

Comment: Can you try to recreate your node pool and see if the issue persist?

Comment: This has happened over at least 2 pools, thanks for checking though. The kube-dns pod's node getting preempted sounds like exactly the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your cluster has only preemptible instances, the system pods will also restart every 24 hours (at least), including [`kube-dns`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).
You have a couple of options:

1. Create another node pool (Of-course, this node pool doesn't have to include TPU nodes, you can try and use `n1-standard-1`, or even cheaper instances) in that GKE cluster to host the critical pods (e.g. `kube-dns`), and add a [`nodeSelector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) field with that node pool to the critical deployments. For example:

```
nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: critical-node-pool
```

2. The number of `kube-dns` replicas is determined by `kube-dns-autoscaler` deployment. Increasing the number of `kube-dns` pods can help you make your system more resilient to node preemption. You can increase by editing the `kube-dns-autoscaler` ConfigMap in `kube-system` namespace.
   Edit the ConfigMap with `kubectl edit configmap dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system`. Look for this line: `linear: '{"coresPerReplica":256,"min":1,"nodesPerReplica":16}'`.
   As explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/#tuning-autoscaling-parameters), the "min" field indicates the minimal number of DNS bakends. You can increase the minimum number of replicas, or tweak the other parameters the satisfy your needs.
   If you use the Auto-Scaling, don't set the minimum number of `kube-dns` replicas to an higher number than your minimal node count in that cluster, as it'll keep the nodes up just to due to deployment of `kube-dns`, and with no relation to your application workload.

Comment: I went with your approach (1), using the taint/toleration idea from https://gist.github.com/OlegGorj/ba2bd4ad3f2a31af89a1eb94667da9e0 - "gcloud container clusters create" specifies "--node-taints" - criticals take up most of an n1-standard-1, all working well.